# Processing a large vector crashes the program with bad_alloc

Tags: c++

I have a large `vector<string>` (about 1 million in size) that I need to process:

```
stringstream numStr;
cout << "before loop" << endl;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numList.size(); i++) {
    cout << i << ": " << ((NORM_MAX - NORM_MIN) * (atoi(numList[i].c_str()) - min)) / (max - min) + NORM_MIN << endl;
    int number = ((NORM_MAX - NORM_MIN) * (atoi(numList[i].c_str()) - min)) / (max - min) + NORM_MIN;
    numStr << number;
    numList[i] = numStr.str();
}
```

However, the program crashes upon reaching 36691 ~ 36693

```
(snip)  
36689: 288  
36690: 264  
36691: 245  

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

What can I do to find out the cause of this problem?

Comment: Looks like you tried to allocate more memory than your OS was willing/able to give you.

Comment: It looks like `numStr` is going to grow to be very large.  That could be the sort of the `bad_alloc` which indicates that a memory allocation has failed.  I'd bet that the append to `numStr` is failing.

Comment: You can deal with each part of the data, do not have all the data to be loaded into memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code stands right now, you have the `stringstream` **outside the loop**, which means you are continuously appending new numbers to the end of the existing stream over and over, and then storing the *ENTIRE LIST* on each loop iteration:

```
numList[i]   = "... 288"
numList[i+1] = "... 288 264"
numList[i+2] = "... 288 264 245"
```

And so on...

So yes, that will *eventually* run out of memory trying to allocate a *single* `string` that has the *entire list* of numbers formatted in it, if `numList.size()` is very large.

You likely meant to put the `stringstream` **inside the loop** instead, so that each iteration formats and stores a *single* `int` value in each `numList` slot:

```
cout << "before loop" << endl;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numList.size(); i++) {
    int number = ((NORM_MAX - NORM_MIN) * (atoi(numList[i].c_str()) - min)) / (max - min) + NORM_MIN;
    cout << i << ": " << number << endl;
    stringstream numStr;
    numStr << number;
    numList[i] = numStr.str();
}
```

```
numList[i]   = "288"
numList[i+1] = "264"
numList[i+2] = "245"
```

And so on...

Comment: Thank you! Completely overlooked that it appends instead of replacing it.